# Recursive CTE finding the first manager in hierarchy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a users table

[image]

and I want to find for every user their first manager by their working location hierarchy.

I managed to write this script, but I can't seem to make it work properly. I need that user 1003 has to have 1001 managerId. Now it shows 1002.

[image]

```
select 1001 as userid, 'L1' as locationCode, NULL as parentLocationCode, 1 as isManager into #Users union all
select 1002 as userid, 'L2' as locationCode, 'L1' as parentPad, 0 as isManager union all
select 1003 as userid, 'L3' as locationCode, 'L2' as parentPad, 0 as isManager 

;WITH cte_org AS (
    SELECT       
        d.userid 
        ,d.locationCode
        ,d.parentLocationCode
        ,d.isManager
        ,null as managerId
    FROM       
        #Users as d
    WHERE d.parentLocationCode is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        d.userid 
        ,d.locationCode
        ,d.parentLocationCode
        ,d.isManager
        ,o.userid as managerId
    FROM 
        #Users as d
        inner JOIN cte_org o on d.parentLocationCode=o.locationCode
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_org
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set managerId using userId for manager then replicate managerId to linked records

```
select 1001 as userid, 'L1' as locationCode, NULL as parentLocationCode, 1 as isManager into #Users union all
select 1002 as userid, 'L2' as locationCode, 'L1' as parentPad, 0 as isManager union all
select 1003 as userid, 'L3' as locationCode, 'L2' as parentPad, 0 as isManager 
;

WITH
cte_org AS (
    SELECT       
        d.userid 
        ,d.locationCode
        ,d.parentLocationCode
        ,d.isManager
        ,d.userid as managerId
    FROM       
        #Users as d
    WHERE d.parentLocationCode is NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        d.userid 
        ,d.locationCode
        ,d.parentLocationCode
        ,d.isManager
        ,o.managerId as managerId
    FROM 
        #Users as d
        inner JOIN cte_org o on d.parentLocationCode=o.locationCode
)
SELECT *
FROM cte_org
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

userid  locationCode    parentLocationCode  isManager   managerId
1001    L1                                  1           1001
1002    L2              L1                  0           1001
1003    L3              L2                  0           1001
```